# iOS - Drag and drop an object "into" another object

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I have 2 `UIImageView`. The firs can be moved by the user and have to be dragged "into" another. I have to detect when the first image view is "into" the other.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just control if the frames of the `UIImageView` are contained each other.

```
UIImageView * a;
UIImageView * b;

if (CGRectContainsRect(a.frame, b.frame)) {
     NSLog(@"a is over b");
}
```

Comment: Works! One things, in this case, b is over a.